# meta.* reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why is my meta.gaming rep the same (minus lag) as my gaming rep? Is rep on the meta sites not valuable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voting on Meta is not for rewarding good questions, by giving good reputation to the asker.
It is used more Meta-gamely.
It displays community approval of point of the questions,
and community preference in the answers (solutions/recommendations) given.

Not having your reputation be punished for making unpopular suggestions on meta is important.
Knowing that it wouldn't hurt my rep, I could provide [this suggestion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/ask-question-animation-is-really-tacky-and-looks-bad),
even though I thought it was quiet likely, to be voted down.
I even told people to vote it down if they thought it a bad suggestion, because this is the mechanic that Meta uses. Right now, it is at -15 votes, this would have cost me 30 reputation, and have cost 15 people 1 rep to vote it down as a poor suggestion.

This was a unpopular suggestion, not a badly written question. **Meta works different**, and that is Ok.

> **Voting is different on meta.**
>   ...
>   Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to
>   discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself
>   behaves, as well as how the software itself works. **On posts tagged
>   feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the
>   proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post
>   itself.**
>   From [help](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

To allow for this, reputation is not tracked on Meta.

Comment: Is there a reason you felt the need to write this new answer to a nearly four year old question?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I stubbled into it, saw it didn't have a Accepted answer, felt it was a valid question, thought I could provide a clearer answer. I didn't check the date. To my knowledge, no stack exchange site has a policy against Necromancy. (but if I am wrong please link, happy to learn)

Comment: No, no policy against it... it just seemed like a somewhat odd choice of question to resurrect; it does have multiple up voted answers. Acceptance is at times a poor metric to go on -  especially on Meta.

Comment: This is true. I felt my answer contributed additionally, it may not have.

Comment: this addresses the reasoning behind the facts, not just the facts like the other 2 answers.

Comment: @antony.trupe - You waited 4 years for the right answer? Now THAT'S perserverence!

Comment: @Oxinabox - There's no policy against it, there's even a [specific badge](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) for it.

Answer (score 7):

See https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/faq

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the parent website, and synchronized hourly. Your reputation here, is the same as your reputation on the parent website. Votes here do not affect your reputation on the parent site.
>
> (However, please note that offensive penalties, if levied by the community through spam or offensive votes on your posts here, will affect your reputation on the parent website.)

Comment: so why do we have a reputation tab on the recent activity page?

Comment: I guess informative @Kip

Comment: Why is this any different from the rest of the stackexchange sites? On stackoverflow.com on meta you have reputation following the same principles of the main site.

Comment: @Fofole. SO meta is a bit different, due to historical anomalies.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Your meta reputation will carry over from the main site.

Comment: I see no value in voting on anything on meta.* now. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the point is that you never have more rep on the meta site than the main site itself. It also means that down-voting doesn't carry the same connotations.

Comment: @antony.trupe Reputation is a side-effect of voting. The reason you vote on something should always be to bump it up to the top because you think it's a good answer, not because it earns someone rep.

Comment: @antony.trupe Also, voting here on meta shows whether you agree with the asker's idea, not whether it is a good idea or not