# Why is the reputation on meta and on main synchronized?

Tags: support, meta

I know there seems to be two duplicated to this question but one points to the other and the other (which [Jeff answered](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/77/7114)) fail to explain why it is like this. I approve the StackOverflow Meta philosophy more.

So, why isn't it like Meta StackOverflow on all other Meta websites?

Comment: In short, because MSO is a special snowflake (for one) and (for two) "**What does voting mean here?** Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. On Meta, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion."