# Ask Question animation is really Tacky and looks bad

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

This is a request to counter what was done for [Here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover), from the basis of [Here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/ask-question-is-not-really-obvious-as-a-button).
I believe (and you can feel free to disagree and vote this down, to indicate as such)
it should be changed to something that is not animated.

The static image (so you know which I am talking about) is:
[image: Ask Question]

Animations are tacky and "90's", 
and distracting. 
The animation itself is high quality work,
but the use of a animation at all is tacky.

A google search will turn up many articles like [this](http://blog.hostbaby.com/2012/01/why-flash-websites-can-be-bad-for-business/).
Consider [this question on UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15066/examples-of-good-use-of-animation-on-web-pages)
And [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15898/blinking-bouncing-and-flashing-elements/17481#17481) (mostly about constant animations, in the question, but the answers talk about animation in general).
Are we following the recommendations there?

I recommend a more subtle change. (Perhaps the lights might flash).

I suspect most people will disagree with me, and that is okay,
we will then have established community consensus.

Comment: [Ummm....](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover)

Comment: Ah, I skipped over the feature request, however since it is status-complete, am I more correct to post a new one, that to put up an answer on that one?

Comment: @kalina Does not count.

Comment: @Oxinabox That feature request got 99 upvotes and *one* downvote. Lazers are *overwhelmingly* popular with users of this site. Also the UX.SE questions you have linked **support our use of animation for this button** - We are animating the button only when it is in focus, and doing so in a way that does not break SEO, and degrades gracefully if not supported by the browser.

Comment: They can be interpreted to be in support, they can be interpreted to be against. This is why I said to *Consider* them, because I wanted people to thing about it. Which you clearly have done, and came to a considered conclusion, well done.

Comment: +1 for the courage to raise your concern. Plus I think saying "let's leave it slightly animated, but the current animation isn't good" is a legitimate proposal.

Comment: Given this was recently **re**-implemented for the new design, I think it's fair to say that lazors are sticking around, so marking this as [status-declined]

Answer (score 13):

[image: See comments for the actual answer.]

Comment: -1, does not add meaningfully to discussion. Other than saying perhaps "Laser are pretty cool. Lets keep lasers." Could be improved with use of words.

Comment: This doesn't need to be discussed, [it has already been discussed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover). This only needs to provide an answer.

Comment: You know, "Laser are pretty cool. Lets keep lasers" is pretty much 99% of the reason why we should have this feature

Comment: +1 - Answer contains animated lasers.

Comment: @kalina: The Meta you linked had no discussion of "Is this is a good idea." Only of "How it should look". That likely indicates the overwhelming community support. However your comment is misleading/incorrect, it has has the potential for discussion

Comment: @Oxinabox The decision to animate the lazers was in fact originally a UX-based decision. [Here is the original discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1212/3610), which has 32 upvotes and *one* downvote. It was the most-upvoted answer the question of how to animate the button by far. kalina is right, we have had this discussion.

Comment: Fredley, I linked that question, (and at your suggestion the one kalina linked) in my question. Thinking on it thought you are correct (Kalina had the wrong link, and should have used the that one)

Comment: +1 Transformers are cool.

Comment: Nothing wrong with revisiting the discussion, although from the responses here it looks like the community's view is unchanged. (Disclaimer, I don't always enjoy lazors, but when I do, they're mothership lazors)

Answer (score 13):

The community is strongly in favour of lasers. The site's demographic likes them a lot.

If you don't want lasers, I suggest [removing them with a userstyle](http://userstyles.org/styles/96724/you-are-aweful-and-you-hate-lasers).
(For Stylish, unfun, users)
This is based on Fredley's Userscript answer, but as a Userstlye

Comment: This is a clear and useful answer to have, thank you.

Comment: Alot of lasers.

Comment: As an added note about your UX concerns: it's a non-intrusive animation and doesn't obscure anything at all. Since the wanted demographic for the site are gamers who tend to like fancy effects it's not hurting, it's helping. (overgeneralizasions aside).

Comment: Please do not roll back edits which improve spelling and provide a complete solution.

Comment: @kalina: I have rolled back your change, because UserStyles and UserScripts are two different things. (I will give you a chance to respond be fore I roll back again. Let me me get on chat)

Comment: @kalina [Alot of lasers](http://i.imgur.com/1vOCaMV.png)

Comment: @Oxinabox In this instance the userscript is changing the CSS so it's effectively doing the same job. By having the link in your answer you're providing a solution rather than speculating. Additionally, "alot" isn't a word, it's a creature. Not trying to cause friction, merely trying to help you provide a complete solution. ([Link to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge))

Comment: No, the Userscript is changing the CSS, however a Userstyle will load alot faster, (in the render stage, vs in the script run stage.)
Use of a userscript to do this can make the site, jitter on slower connections/computers. 
Also they are just plain different things, I personally (and others) don't use userscripts, but do use userstyles. There is already a answer that talks about userstyles, a Seperate one can exist for Userscripts

Comment: Don't talk geek to me, I'm just a pony.

Comment: All is well. And the glory that is stack exchange, and communication, prevails over war, even of the infields

Answer (score 8):

## [Here is a userscript to disable the effect](https://stackapps.com/q/4472/4644)

...if it really does bother you so much. In order to install it you'll need to drag it into your extensions page (Chrome) or use Greasemonkey (Firefox). All it does is replace the css for the hover effect, and remind you that you're an awful person.